# Minor tag summary display bug

Tags: bug, tags, tag-excerpt

Here's the current tag summary for [opalrb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opalrb):

> Opal is a fast and very small (<40kB) Ruby-to-JavaScript compiler that can be run in any browser.

On the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opalrb/info), it displays correctly:

[image: tag info page image]

However, the summary is cut off on the [search result page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opalrb):

[image: search result page image]

It looks like the less-than sign is causing a problem...

Comment: The string isn't present as a hidden tag either. it's just cut off there.

Comment: Maybe overzealous HTML sanitization?

Comment: Definitely sanitisation - see [pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe) - it has `<unistd.h>` in [its excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/info), and that text doesn't appear on the search page.  Seems it's stripping `<` and `>` and everything in between, but the opalrb tag doesn't have a `>`, so it just removes the lot.

Comment: As a complete HTML illiterate person: shouldn't anything missing even a single `>` be safe?

Comment: As a complete HTML illiterate person: couldn't this be fixed by replacing `<` with `&lt;`?

Comment: Why not just edit it to say "less than"? Lot's more typing, but is it really a massive effort? The other example perhaps "in the header unistd.h" or something written in English by someone with more domain-specific knowledge

Comment: @BillWoodger Although that would solve these specific instances of the problem, it'd really just be a work-around; an avoidance of the bug, rather than an actual fix. Given that the summary *does* display correctly elsewhere, I'd imagine that this would be a trivial thing to remedy.